# Can I use an image to trigger a modal window in Bootstrap?

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, modal-window

Simple question really. Instead of having a button trigger a modal window, I need to use an image. I can't figure out the code to do it. Any tips?

Comment: trigger <a> and wrap it in the image

Answer (score 8):

Yes you just wrap the  tag around an image.

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal">

<img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
```

Here is a live example:

[Bootstrap modal trigger by an image](http://jsfiddle.net/cwGcR/1/)